# Cuda printf() overlapping when using multiple devices

Tags: cuda

I have a printf in my `__global__` code. It works as intended most of the time. However when using a multi GPU system (typically happens when ran on an 4-8 GPU system), once in a while, the prints will merge. By once in a while Its about 100-500 lines out of 167000 lines.

I was wondering how this situation can be remedied without adding too much overhead of transferring the data back to host (if possible). I was thinking to try a mutex lock for printing but I dont think that sort of thing exists for use in the kernel. Any other solutions I could try?

**Note:** The actual kernel is a long running kernel usually around 20-50 minutes to complete depending on the GPU.

**Note2:** I barely know what I'm doing with C/C++.

Example of merged Output

```
JmHp8rwXAw,031aa97714c800de47971829beded204000cfcf5e0f3775552ccf3e9b387869fxLuZJu3ZkX
qVOuKlQ0ZcMrhGXAnZ75,08bf3e90a57c31b7f355214cdf442748d9ff6ae1d49a96f7a8b9e3c86bd8e68a,5231a9e969d53c64f75bb1f07b1c95bb81f685744ed46f56348c733389c56ca5
,623f62b3198c8b62cd7a3b3cf8bf8ede5f9bfdccb7c1dc48a55530c7d5f59ce8
```

What it should look like

```
JmHp8rwXAw,031aa97714c800de47971829beded204000cfcf5e0f3775552ccf3e9b387869f
MrhGXAnZ75,08bf3e90a57c31b7f355214cdf442748d9ff6ae1d49a96f7a8b9e3c86bd8e68a
qVOuKlQ0Zc,5231a9e969d53c64f75bb1f07b1c95bb81f685744ed46f56348c733389c56ca5
xLuZJu3ZkX,623f62b3198c8b62cd7a3b3cf8bf8ede5f9bfdccb7c1dc48a55530c7d5f59ce8
```

My Example Code:

```cpp
#define BLOCKS 384
#define THREADS 64

typedef struct HandlerInput {
    unsigned char device;
} HandlerInput;

pthread_mutex_t solutionLock;

__global__ void kernel(unsigned long baseSeed) {
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    BYTE random[RANDOM_LEN];
    BYTE data[DIGEST_LEN];
    SHA256_CTX ctx;

    /* Randomization routine*/
    d_getRandomString((unsigned long)idx + baseSeed, random);

    /* Hashing routine*/
    sha256_hash(&ctx, random, data, RANDOM_LEN);

    /* Print to console - randomStr,Hash */
    printf("%s,%s\n", random, data);
}

void *launchGPUHandlerThread(void *vargp) {

    HandlerInput *hi = (HandlerInput *)vargp;
    cudaSetDevice(hi->device);

    unsigned long rngSeed = timeus();

    while (1) {
        hostRandomGen(&rngSeed);
        kernel<<<BLOCKS, THREADS>>>(rngSeed);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    }
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    int GPUS;
    cudaGetDeviceCount(&GPUS);
    pthread_t *tids = (pthread_t *)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * GPUS);

    for (int i = 0; i < GPUS; i++) {
        HandlerInput *hi = (HandlerInput *)malloc(sizeof(HandlerInput));
        hi->device = i;
        pthread_create(tids + i, NULL, launchGPUHandlerThread, hi);
        usleep(23);
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&solutionLock);

    for (int i = 0; i < GPUS; i++)
        pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf` in kernel code still has to send data to the host. I always considered to be a debugging feature and would have never used it in production code (Not sure how much parallelism is left when using it). Given that the data has to be sent to the host anyway, I would propose doing it manually s.t. you can control how it is printed from the host. Due to the kind of data you probably need to cooperate through shared memory to get memory coalescing.

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#formatted-output) don't mention anything about `printf` being bad for performance, so I might be wrong on that point. On the other hand there has to be some kind of synchronization, I would think. And noone would argue against `print` inside a hot loop being very slow in host code. Either way I don't see how one would be able to avoid these overlaps without a global (i.e. accessible by all GPUs) lock which might be implementable in theory but extremely slow in practice.

Comment: With the right HPC hardware [GPUDirect Storage](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpudirect-storage) might be an option to avoid the host being a bottleneck, but this seems a bit far-fetched.

Comment: Yea i ended up at the same conclusion as you did. I can't really find anything specific regarding multiple GPU's use of the printf function. I only used it because it was incredibly fast (like 50x faster) compared to copying from device to host between iterations. (in the end i redirect stdout to file regardless) I wish I knew what the kernel `printf` was doing behind the scenes so I could imitate it but include the functionality of a lock. `pthread_mutex_lock()` was not accessible by the kernel code and I am not sure how to implement a lock otherwise.

Comment: @poleonix that GPUDirect Storage looks interesting. I will look into it, however the hardware is being rented through vastai so its not in my control. The only other thing would be for me to better understand what the Cuda Streams are, and maybe if I can use those in a way to make this work. But all the examples I can find are so generic and nonsensical. Makes me miss the point of what they can be used for, or if they would be helpful in this case.

Comment: CUDA streams are primarily for having multiple asynchronous kernels on one GPU, I don't think they will be very helpful here. You might want to contact that hardware provider about GPUDirect Storage, maybe it's not that long of a shot. One would implement a lock using [atomics](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) (the `_system` variety should work for the multi-GPU case). I guess the lock variable would be in unified memory, so all GPUs can access it.

Comment: When naively implementing the transfer to host memory, you would get uncoalesced accesses which are very bad for performance. That is why one would put all the data into shared memory and redistribute it in such a way that one gets coalescing among each block. See [How to Access Global Memory Efficiently in CUDA C/C++ Kernels (CUDA Dev Blog)](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/how-access-global-memory-efficiently-cuda-c-kernels/)

Comment: "The docs don't mention anything about printf being bad for performance, " <- printf kills performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent 4 days trying different things to no avail. I really don't understand memory management enough in C/C++ to get past the endless segmentation fault errors.

What I ended up doing was using [Unified Memory](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/unified-memory-cuda-beginners/) as it seemed the easiest way to handle the memory for both device and host and it doesn't seem to add too much overhead to the whole process. Then each cpu thread (gpu) can write to its own file. I ran a couple of nvprof and it seemed that after the initial setup for the memory `cudaMallocManaged` the rest of the overhead seemed to be measured in the microseconds. Since each loop takes 20 minutes these are really barely noticeable.

I created two `__device__` functions to copy the data over to the host accessible arrays, because I wanted to utilize the `#pragma unroll` feature. Not really sure if that helps or what it even does, but I decided to do things this way.

If anyone has further suggestions on ways to improve I am open to trying more things out.

Here is my new example code:

```
#define BLOCKS 384
#define THREADS 64

typedef struct HandlerInput {
    unsigned char device;
} HandlerInput;

__device__ void mycpydigest(__restrict__ BYTE *dst, __restrict__ const BYTE *src) {
#pragma unroll 64
    for (BYTE i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        dst[i] = src[i];
    }
    dst[64] = '\0';
}

__device__ void mycpyrandom(__restrict__ BYTE *dst, __restrict__ const BYTE *src) {
#pragma unroll 10
    for (BYTE i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        dst[i] = src[i];
    }
    dst[10] = '\0';
}

__global__ void kernel(BYTE **d_random, BYTE **d_hashes, unsigned long baseSeed) {
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    BYTE random[RANDOM_LEN];
    BYTE data[DIGEST_LEN];
    SHA256_CTX ctx;

    /* Randomization routine*/
    d_getRandomString((unsigned long)idx + baseSeed, random);

    /* Hashing routine*/
    sha256_hash(&ctx, random, data, RANDOM_LEN);

    /* Send to host - randomStr & Hash */
    mycpydigest(d_hashes[idx], data);
    mycpyrandom(d_random[idx], random);

}

void *launchGPUHandlerThread(void *vargp) {

    HandlerInput *hi = (HandlerInput *)vargp;
    cudaSetDevice(hi->device);

    unsigned long rngSeed = timeus();

    int threadBlocks = hi->BLOCKS * hi->THREADS;

    BYTE **randoms;
    BYTE **hashes;

    cudaMallocManaged(&randoms, sizeof(BYTE *) * (threadBlocks), cudaMemAttachGlobal);
    cudaMallocManaged(&hashes, sizeof(BYTE *) * (threadBlocks), cudaMemAttachGlobal);

    for (int i = 0; i < threadBlocks; i++) {
        cudaMallocManaged(&randoms[i], sizeof(BYTE) * (RANDOM_LEN), cudaMemAttachGlobal);
        cudaMallocManaged(&hashes[i], sizeof(BYTE) * (DIGEST_LEN), cudaMemAttachGlobal);
    }

    while (1) {
        hostRandomGen(&rngSeed);
        kernel<<<hi->BLOCKS, hi->THREADS>>>(randoms, hashes, rngSeed);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        print2File(randoms, hashes, threadBlocks, hi->device)
    }
    cudaFree(hashes);
    cudaFree(randoms);
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    int GPUS;
    cudaGetDeviceCount(&GPUS);
    pthread_t *tids = (pthread_t *)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * GPUS);

    for (int i = 0; i < GPUS; i++) {
        HandlerInput *hi = (HandlerInput *)malloc(sizeof(HandlerInput));
        hi->device = i;
        pthread_create(tids + i, NULL, launchGPUHandlerThread, hi);
        usleep(23);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < GPUS; i++)
        pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to thank [@paleonix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10107454/paleonix) for the help in the comments. I was working on this issue for a week before I posted and your comments helped guide me down a different path.